# Android Studio wont start up

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio, stack-overflow

Android Studio on my 64 bit laptop won't start. It stays on the Android Studio loading/splash screen.

Things I've tried and other information:

- The JDK path is correct. It's the 1.8 version.
- I have 8GB of RAM.
- I have uninstalled and reinstalled it.
- I have the SDK installed. I referenced it when I reinstalled Android Studio.
- I have restarted my laptop.
- I have tried running it as an Administrator.
- I do have Full control of the Android folder and the studio64.exe file.
- It shows up in the Background processes section of my Task Manager.

I thought that I'd add more insight to my situation... I've had Android Studio on this laptop for a year, I finally decided to set it up with my GitHub so I could push commits directly from it. I did a bit of coding for a couple more hours then closed it. I tried to open it two days later (today) and this happened.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByPkdSc_1g2ARDRBR0NETXNCWUE/view?usp=sharing This is the screen shot.

About 6 hours later I get a dialog box telling me there's a Stack Overflow error:

at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)

This is the full message:

```
Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.RuntimeException:   com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.openapi.util.registry.RegistryState'
at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:178)
at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at    java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.openapi.util.registry.RegistryState'
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:248)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:39)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:590)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:610)
at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:245)
at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:211)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:125)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:359)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:116)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:87)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl.load(ApplicationStoreImpl.java:101)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:504)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:486)
at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:170)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.LocalFileSystem.getInstance(LocalFileSystem.java:44)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ApplicationStoreImpl$1.beforeFileBasedStorageCreate(ApplicationStoreImpl.java:85)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.StateStorageManagerImpl.createFileStateStorage(StateStorageManagerImpl.java:212)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.StateStorageManagerImpl.createStateStorage(StateStorageManagerImpl.java:185)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.StateStorageManagerImpl.getStateStorage(StateStorageManagerImpl.java:102)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ComponentStoreImpl.initPersistentComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.java:315)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.stores.ComponentStoreImpl.initComponent(ComponentStoreImpl.java:75)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.initializeComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:182)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:566)
... 27 more
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.ManagingFS'
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:248)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:39)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:590)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:610)
at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:245)
at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:211)
at org.picocontainer.defaults.BasicComponentParameter.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:77)
at org.picocontainer.defaults.ComponentParameter.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:114)
at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructorArguments(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:257)
at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:217)
at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
at com.intellij.util.pico.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:58)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:550)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:610)
at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:245)
at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:211)
at org.picocontainer.defaults.CollectionComponentParameter.getArrayInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:268)
at org.picocontainer.defaults.CollectionComponentParameter.resolveInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:127)
at org.picocontainer.defaults.ComponentParameter.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:116)
at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getConstructorArguments(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:257)
at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter$1.run(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:217)
at org.picocontainer.defaults.ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.java:53)
at org.picocontainer.defaults.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:248)
at com.intellij.util.pico.ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:58)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter$1.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:550)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:610)
at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:245)
at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:211)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponentFromContainer(ComponentManagerImpl.java:168)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.getComponentFromContainer(ApplicationImpl.java:538)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:199)
at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.getComponent(ComponentManagerImpl.java:194)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.VirtualFileManager.getInstance(VirtualFileManager.java:44)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.LocalFileSystem$LocalFileSystemHolder.<clinit>(LocalFileSystem.java:40)
... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:116)
at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:100)
at org.apache.log4j.DefaultThrowableRenderer.render(DefaultThrowableRenderer.java:58)
at org.apache.log4j.spi.ThrowableInformation.getThrowableStrRep(ThrowableInformation.java:87)
at org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.getThrowableStrRep(LoggingEvent.java:413)
at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:313)
at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(RollingFileAppender.java:276)
at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
at org.apache.log4j.Category.info(Category.java:683)
at com.intellij.idea.IdeaLogger.info(IdeaLogger.java:185)
at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.info(Logger.java:97)
at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase.<init>(PersistentEnumeratorBase.java:212)
at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator.<init>(PersistentBTreeEnumerator.java:82)
at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.<init>(PersistentEnumeratorDelegate.java:38)
at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentStringEnumerator.<init>(PersistentStringEnumerator.java:53)
at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentStringEnumerator.<init>(PersistentStringEnumerator.java:46)
at com.intellij.util.io.PersistentStringEnumerator.<init>(PersistentStringEnumerator.java:32)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:243)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.init(FSRecords.java:318)
```

Someone help me please, I really need to work on my project.

Comment: what about the android SDK ?

Comment: That's been installed too, or what do you mean?

Comment: See if the answers [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=87765) helps..

Comment: That's for a different issue, I only get the loading screen in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll just have to tick everything in the uninstall dialog; SDK, User Settings, Intel HAXM... everything. Delete every flipping folder labelled "Android" and restart your computer. Then re-install it.

Ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

This couldn't be a good answer, but did you check that you have 32bit and 64bit JDK? try it and let me know.

Comment: and maybe you need both of jre too, i really don't know

Comment: Yes, everything is the same. I was using Android studio two days ago when I finally decided to set it up with my github account and I exited it after about a couple of hours of programming after that... I opened it today and it this started happening

Comment: for me it sounds more like java problem, or it could be the firewall as well, can you make sure that android studio is allowed from the firewall and antivirus and all these?

Comment: i see you have windows 8.1, open control panel, click Windows firewall, click on the left "Advanced settings", you will see inbound and outbound rules, on each one of them, when you click there will be on the right side "New Rule"... click it, and add the program you want.

Comment: also make sure that it is allowed from the antivirus, each antivirus way is different so just try disabling it for 5 minutes in order to try and see whether it works or not.

Comment: I've added it as a new rule, still nothing.. and I have no antivirus (I know). Windows Defender is the only thing I've got.

Comment: i found another solution that could work, as i read on the internet this seems to be a network connection problem. check this site https://codevomit.wordpress.com/2014/12/12/starting-android-studio-behind-a-proxy/

Comment: you might have an unstable internet connection, a good way to check that is simply check your internet speed on a website such as www.speedtest.net , chose a server near you and click it, if you have a low ping and the needle is "stable" then the network connection is fine.

Comment: I tried what the article suggested, it still doesn't work sadly plus, I don't think it's a connection related problem cause I've had to work on a project at school and the internet connection is very limited, and very unstable at times and it worked fine.

Comment: well then, if i find anything else i will post it here, you know these reasons are the reason i stick with eclipse.